# I have an ADO recordset, now I want to create a table from it but not at its connection location. How?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been googling this for a couple days and am failing. I know I did something like this years ago but it's been a long time.

The idea is that I am querying a table in one Access file, breaking the connection then want to drop it in a different Access file. I'm doing this multiple times so I don't want to hardcode each create table statement.

```
dim sql as string

Set selfconnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objconnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set selfRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

selfconnection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & "Data Source = C:\this File.accdb"
selfRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM datasources", selfconnection, 0, 1
'''At this point I have a recordset of multiple tables I need to query and what fields.

Do Until selfRecordset.EOF '''this loop should query every table listed in my datasources table
  sql = "SELECT  " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("columnName") & " FROM " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("tableName")
  objconnection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & "Data Source = " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("dataLocation")
  objrecordset.Open sql, objconnection, 0, 1
  objconnection.Close
  '''I have now pulled in a recordset that contains only the fields I want and have broken the connection. 
  '''I'd like to offload this recordset into selfconnention

  '''I have tried this
  With objrecordset
    Set .ActiveConnection = selfconnection
    objrecordset.updatebatch
  End With
  '''If I don't close objconnection I get "can not do when connection is open" 
  '''if I do close it I get "can not do when connection is closed"
```

Looking around, the general answer seems to be something like creating an INSERT query which is great but I need an existing table for the that to work and as I mentioned, I don't want to hardcode a CREATE TABLE for each one of these. I've seen the recommendation of SELECT INTO but given that I'm changing which file it's in, I don't think I can do this.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: After the help below I switch to a doCmd.transferdatabase. The curious part of me still wonders about the question as asked however, this addresses my issue by getting table into my Access file without manually opening the other file and I can then manipulate my copy as needed without any risk to the source data.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you put the target table name in the list of tables to query, it shouldn't be hard to use CREATE TABLE without hardcoding each table name.

Comment: I have that. All the examples I've seen so far explicitly create that table, field by field:
   CREATE TABLE foo (
      indexfield CHAR(50)
     ,secondfield INT
   )

rather than 
    CREATE TABLE foo AS(
        SELECT * FROM bar
    )

can you help me get over that syntax hurdle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the docmd.TransferDatabase to copy over the table you want. your issue is not clear, so i am making assumptions here. if  you don't want to export an entire table, then create a query that just reads the columns you want to export, and store the name of that query in your datasources table. then, just call this as you are looping through, and pass it the query name and target db.

Note, this expects that the target database already exists, if it doesn't then you need to create it, google for that. and this will also over-write the existing table in your target db, so if you want to append, then it won't work.

Create a query on the fly by adding this sub:

```
Sub EditQuery(sqlText As String)
 On Error Resume Next
  DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "qTemp"
  CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef "qTemp", sqlText
End Sub
```

then call the above:

```
 EditQuery ("SELECT " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("columnName") & " FROM " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("tableName"))
```

finally call:

```
 Call DoCmd.TransferDatabase(TransferType:=acExport, _
                            DatabaseType:="Microsoft Access", _
                            databaseName:=selfRecordset.Fields.Item("dataLocation"), _
                            ObjectType:=acTable, _
                            Source:="qTemp", Destination:=selfRecordset.Fields.Item("tableName"))
```

by the way, this should be run from the source database, not destination.

Comment: Oh, this looks promising. I'll go play with this and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Can you validate that I have this laid out right?
    Call DoCmd.TransferDatabase(TransferType:=acImport, DatabaseType:="Microsoft Access", _
     DatabaseName:=selfRecordset.Fields.Item("dataLocation"), ObjectType:=acTable, _
     Source:=selfRecordset.Fields.Item("tableName"), Destination:=selfRecordset.Fields.Item("tableName"))

When I run that I get that the table does not exists. However, when I run this, I get results: "SELECT  " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("columnName") & " FROM " & selfRecordset.Fields.Item("tableName")

 I'm running this from the destination database.

Comment: looks like you are creating the query on the fly, for that to work, you need an actual query. so create a query on the fly, and then use the name of that query. i will modify the answer to clarify in a minute

Comment: made one more correction, please look at edits in answer

Comment: I haven't yet given your above answer a shot but I wanted to ask, is it possible to do it from the destination? (documentation seems really lacking on this when I google). The whole reason for jumping through these hoops is that the owners of the source don't want me doing anything to their files. They're essentially using a LAN based Access file as their production system and are super freaked out by me opening the file, running a query and exporting the results. I'm trying to make them more comfortable by writing a query that can't change their files. 

Now off to play with what you sent.

Comment: i thought the config was in the source database. you can do the reverse, surely now you are importing. the sql created in the editsql will need the correct syntax, meaning, it needs to be able to reference the external file, so that you should be able to figure out.